Select all unique values in SQL table with additional information
I'm trying to find the first SeqGrp and SeqNum of the first unique values TaxGroupCode. I had this query in a MS Access database (shown below), but we recently started using SQL Server 2008 instead.
However, it seems FIRST isn't a valid function in T-SQL (at least in this version).
SELECT
    FIRST(DesotoCoPA_Trims.SeqGrp) & "-" &  FIRST(DesotoCoPA_Trims.SeqNum), "Tax District " & DesotoCoPA_Trims.TaxGroupCode AS Sample
FROM  
    DesotoCoPA_Trims
GROUP BY 
    DesotoCoPA_Trims.TaxGroupCode;

This produces:
GrpSeq  Sample
-----------------------
2-28    Tax District 2   
5-31    Tax District 3   
6-2123  Tax District 7   
6-2128  Tax District 1   
6-9694  Tax District 6    

I'm relatively new to SQL, so I have no idea how to get around this problem. I don't need the results to be formatted this way specifically.

FIRST() is an odd bird. In a real relational databases, there is no such thing as a true "first" row absent an explicit ORDER BY. Databases can and sometimes will give you different results for the same sql on the same data from run to run of the query.

1 - SQL Server 2008? Seriously?  It's been out of support for 4 or 5 years.  2.  Don't know what exactly the first function in Access does, maybe look at first_value ?

Also, SQL Server 2008 already reached formal end of life status more than 5 years ago now. That means it hasn't any patches in a long time... not even critical security updates. It's dangerous and irresponsible to still be using it, especially as the any database small enough to fit in Access is likely to also fit in the free Express Edition of the current release. If you get to a more recent edition, you can at least use First_Value(), which will have you set an ORDER BY.

This is a weird query. As far as I know there is no documentation on what MS Access considers the FIRST row of a group. In other words, you'll get values from arbitrarily picked rows. Then you try to remove duplicates with DISTINCT, but there cannot be duplicates, because you group by taxgroupcode and select the taxgroupcode. I suggest, before trying to convert this query from MS Access to SQL Server, think about what this query is really meant to do and fix it.

Thorsten, you are correct. I removed the DISTINCT and got the same results.

You need to get to a newer version of SQL Server. There are two reasons for this.
One reason is SQL Server 2008 is hopelessly out of date. It hasn't had any patches or updates in more than 5 years... not even critical security updates. It's dangerous and iresponsible to still be using it. I understand you may not be in a position to make this change directly, but you likely are in a position to push this need (not want!) up the chain.
The other reason is newer versions of SQL Server will let you easily solve this issue.
To understand how, first I need to explain something about relational set theory. Real relational databases do not have any concept at all of the first or last item in a set. Absent an explicit ORDER BY directive they are free to return rows in any order they find convenient. This will commonly match the order stored on disk or from the primary key, but there are a number of things that can change this for a given run of a query. That is, a database can (and sometimes WILL) give different results from the same sql on the same data.
That's not good. The First() function from Access violates this principle, and so was never added to most serious database products.
Recent versions of SQL Server have something called Window Functions, one of which is First_Value(). This function is part of the ANSI standard, and makes use of an OVER clause where you will include a ORDER BY definition, so you can get deterministic results. This is the closest direct-match to the First() function from access.
It's also often easier to use row_number() and then wrap the query so you can have a WHERE clause limit the results to rows where row_number() was 1 (this also replaces the GROUP BY clause).
But these functions are not yet available in SQL Server 2008.
Since we need to upgrade anyway, rather than talk about what version added the Window Function feature I'll talk about support and patching. From that lens, the minimum version of SQL Server you should be using today (July 2024) is SQL Server 2016 (formal end of life is July of 2026), but while you're at it you may as well go newer. For example, SQL Server 2022 should continue to get security updates into 2033.
The good news is any database small enough to fit in MS Access is also likely to easily fit within the limits of the free Express Edition of a current SQL Server release. Cost isn't likely to be a barrier, even for commercial use, as long as the Access file wasn't pushing 10 GB. And if you can't install that because the operating system is too old, that's also a critical issue.

Trust me, I brought up the same concerns as soon as 2008 was mentioned. Unfortunately, the version is out of my control and this is what I have to work with for the time being. Is there no workaround to get the desired results with the product version we're on?

Well... show them this post. Anyway, the alternative is waaaay more complicated: writing logic to compute the first value for each set, and then joining to subqueries that match only those rows.

Found a workaround that will take some time to implement, but we're basically going to create an Access DB with linked tables that point to the SQL database. Already tested a couple and the queries work without modification. Apparently, we do have a plan to update to SQL 2022, but we have to work out a few kinks in our current setup before we can migrate over.

Try with Min and Concat:
SELECT  
    CONCAT(MIN(DesotoCoPA_Trims.SeqGrp), '-', MIN(DesotoCoPA_Trims.SeqNum)) AS Sequence, 
    'Tax District ' + DesotoCoPA_Trims.TaxGroupCode AS Sample
FROM  
    DesotoCoPA_Trims
GROUP BY 
    DesotoCoPA_Trims.TaxGroupCode;

Alternatively, if the values aren't numeric:
SELECT  
    MIN(DesotoCoPA_Trims.SeqGrp) + '-' + MIN(DesotoCoPA_Trims.SeqNum) AS Sequence, 
    'Tax District ' + DesotoCoPA_Trims.TaxGroupCode AS Sample


CONCAT isn't available in 2008 either. I think a serious chat with the person in charge of our SQL server is required here.

Oh, then try basic concatenating - see extended answer, please. But, of course, it is time for an upgrade.
